# Any good model for LLM to downloand and use it in local PC?

Tags: large-language-model

Looking for a good LLM model to download and use it in the local PC. Tried the facebook LLaMa model and other models are not that great in terms of the accuracy and respopnse. Looking for a a good model to recommend. Looking to use it in a high end PC or in local server.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the facebook model LLaMa2 from huggingface which will work well

Comment: The answer (and also the question) are opinion-based.

Comment: Please try the Dolly model as well.